# Pass element/function handler to gwt function

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm using GWT to create a client-side only library. I'm using JSNI to call functions is Java from JS. The issue is I'm trying to pass in an element or a function handler and nothing seems to be happening. I don't get an exceptions from GWT or js. Here's my JSNI function with the bridge.

```
public static String testMe(Object obj) 
  {
      return "Response to " + obj.toString();     
  }

  public static native void defineBridgeMethod() /*-{
     $wnd.testMe = function(msg) {
        return @com.mycompany.mywebapp.client.MyWebApp::testMe(Ljava/lang/Object;);
     };

  }-*/;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using `msg`, do you mean to call the function with it as a parameter:

```
public static native void defineBridgeMethod() /*-{
  $wnd.testMe = $entry(function(msg) {
    return @com.mycompany.mywebapp.client.MyWebApp::testMe(Ljava/lang/Object;)(msg);
  });
}-*/;
```

or you can assign the function directly to window:

```
public static native void defineBridgeMethod() /*-{
  $wnd.testMe = $entry(
    @com.mycompany.mywebapp.client.MyWebApp::testMe(Ljava/lang/Object;)
  );
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to export a gwt project to js is using [gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/). Gwtexporter allows to export any gwt project without writing a single line of jsni code and it has plenty of features which allows to customize classes and methods exposed to js, and even it could produce the documentation for your js api.

In your case, implement the `Exportable` interface in the class with your static method, and annotate your method.

```
public class MyClass implements Exportable {
  @Export("$wnd.testMe")
  public static String testMe(Object obj)  {
    return "Response to " + obj.toString();     
  }
}
```

Then you have to call the `exportAll()` method in your entry point and leave the gwt compiler and gwtexporter generator do their magic

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  ExporterUtil.exportAll();
}
```

Here you have a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/wiki/Tutorial_ExportingGwtLibrariesToJavascript_en) of how to export a gwt-library to js, although the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/wiki/GettingStarted) of the project is quite good.

Some of the projects using this technique are [chronoscope](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-chronoscope/wiki/JavaScriptAPI), [gwtupload(jsupload)](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/JsUpload_Documentation) and [gwtquery(jsquery)](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/JsQuery).

Comment: Awesome ! this solution saves a lot of code especially when exporting dozens of methods.

Comment: Yep @user1711180 thats the goal of exporter, you just write your code in 'safe typing' java and mark what you want to expose, you do not worry about jsni internals and syntax. Think that exporter as well deals with type casting, etc.